# In c# in declaring variables and performing operation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mobile-application

I am eager to learn windows application development, so I am learning C#.

I have a doubt that when we are declaring integer variable still we using int.parse() method to perform action.

Can anyone help me in this?

Also I am learning using channel9 videos,still I need to be more expert so I can easily learn windows app development, suggest me some websites.

Also suggest me for windows app development.

Comment: You can declare an int without int.parse() by simplying doing `int i = 10`

Comment: Can you please explain what is difference between for and foreach
In what situation we use foreach,explain me with any example code
thanks

Comment: There are plenty of resources online and in books. They can generally both be used to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Either it is some homework "questionnaire" or you definitely should try it on yourself. Writing some code is the best way to learn it. Look for some examples in the web, copy them, run them, modify them and try to understand what was the effect of your modification.

Comment: This is Not really the thread where you can discuss all these. Please go for c# not a windows-phone-8 tag .... For further clarifications you can go ahead explore the site itself ... All your questions answer are there.

Answer (score 1):

`Int.Parse` is only for converting a numeric string to an integer. It's not the way you declare an integer.
The way you declare an int is the following `int myInt = 10;`

This is how you declare ints in functions:

```
    namespace intpass 
    { 
    class Program 
    { 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
      int myInt = methodPass(5); 
      int b = 20; int z; 
      z = (myInt + b); 
      Console.WriteLine(z); Console.ReadLine(); 
    } 
    private static int methodPass(int c)
    {
      return c + 45; } 
    }
 }
```

Comment: can you please me how to perform simple addition operation using methodpass,like calling one method where it is holding a value of an variable

Comment: I added an example of an int passed to a function

Comment: namespace intpass
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int myInt = methodPass();
            int b = 20;
            int z;
            z = (myInt + b);
            Console.WriteLine(z);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static int methodPass()
        {
            return c=45; 
        }
    }
}

This is the simple am trying

Comment: what mistake i have done,why i cant able to give it as
return c=25;

Comment: You have to declare the variable before you can return it.

Comment: Thanks for you help sir,can you please explain me about difference between for and foreach,in what situation we use foreach method?

Answer (score 0):

int.parse() is used to convert strings to ints.

```
`int num = int.Parse("10");`
```

to simply set num equal to 10 do:

```
`int num = 10;`
```